# EF Table with multiple references to same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Database First Entity Framework Model

Tables:

1) **User**

- Id

2) **Article**:

- Id
- UserCreated > Ref to User last edited User
- UserChanged > Ref to User which created the Article

Enity Framework is Generating a Model like this

```
Partial Public Class Article
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property UserCreated As Integer
Public Property UserChanged As Integer

Public Overridable Property User As User
Public Overridable Property User1 As User

End Class
```

Now I have another table like Vouchers also with UserCreated and UserChanged but names User1 and User.

Is there any way to specific the name of the property without changing the class itself because its generated from the Database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataAnnotation on the UserCreated property to specify the foreign key name:

```
[ForeignKey("UserCreated")]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/gg193958.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change the `property name` for `User1` to any other name using the `edmx-Designer`.

But you should be aware that `User` is the reference to the column `UserCreated`. Because it may be that `User` references to `UserChanged`. You should check that. The best way is to check the name of the relationship. Therefore you need to give the relationship a meaningful name that you are able to distinguish them. Then you can right click on the `relationship line` and retrieve the relationship name.